# How does the heater circuitry work?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic

I have this BreadMaker that I want to modify. I do not have the schematics or the sources. Below is the schematic I draw of the circuitry of the heating element. The microcontroller is 5V and output is only digital I/O or ADC. This is used as an output digital to control the heater element. I see that the schematic around relay is not complete but that's not important for the uncertainties. What I do not understand is:

1) why there are 2 transistors in series

2) the voltage measured with multimeter at microcontroller pin is arround 2V instead of 5V

3) why there is a capacitor in series with microcontroller's output

4) how does the whole circuitry work

5) what's with D4

[image: Breadmaker heating element command]

For reference the microcontroller is SH69P55A and the output is PIN 7. Both transistors are model SS8050. All three diods are same model 1n4148.

Comment: Something about this circuit is wrong. None of the connections around the relay make sense.

Comment: @DKNguyen I have seen that I have drawn wrongly the schmatic for the heating element. I understand electronics to some extent so please be gentile with my mistakes :)

Comment: It looks like some sort of failsafe e.g. in case one transistor fails (although they shouldn't. But the flyback diode appears to be missing so maybe they do. In which case the designer should have fixed the real problem). The input voltage SHOULD appear as 2.5V on a DMM because it's obviously a square wave, rectified (doubled) onto C3. This means it disappears if e.g. the CPU stops generating the square wave, e.g. because it crashed. Also a failsafe, but again begs the question why they are tolerating unreliability instead of fixing it. D4 keeps Q2base 0.7V below Q1 base.

Comment: @jsotola the transistors are correctly drawn and are of type SS8050. I have now added this info also in the question area.

Comment: @BrianDrummond It's a cheap device and I suspect that some extreme conditions such as lighting strikes could cause the MCU to latch up. There is probably hardware protection such as a one-shot thermal fuse to meet UL/CSA safety standards (so it can't cause a fire), however that results in a bricked breadmaker requiring service rather than just one that requires the power to be cycled.

Comment: _"I see that the schematic around relay is not complete but that's not important"_ - We don't know what voltage is powering the relay coil, or what value any of the resistors are. How can that be "not important"?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes, it does have two thermal fuses attached to the metal casing of the oven. They are in series with the main (AC) power supply. So if one opens the whole device will be unpowered.

Comment: @BruceAbbott It does not matter as it is not relevant to the uncertainties that I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *1) why there are 2 transistors in series*

There's a good possibility that they are two MOSFETs wired as a [solid state relay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_relay) or SSR. If they are two NPN transistors as shown this may be some kind of fail-safe-under-one-fault circuit (after all you don't want one BJT to fail short circuit for possible reasons of creating a fire). If that's the case then having two BJTs in series offers some extra protection against this.

> *2) the voltage measured with multimeter at microcontroller pin is
>   arround 2V instead of 5V*

That's likely because the MCU is producing a square wave drive.

> *3) why there is a capacitor in series with microcontroller's output*

It's a safety feature in case the MCU crashes - because it's likely that under normal operation the MCU is producing a square wave output, this can pass through the capacitor and be converted back to a DC level on C3.

> *4) how does the whole circuitry work*

Well, given that there are schematic parts that don't make sense I can't really tell you other than the MCU produces a square wave and this gets through a capacitor and is rectified to produce a control voltage for the SSR (solid state relay) which turns on the heater.

> *5) what's with D4*

This is one area where your schematic is probably wrong or lacking information.

Comment: The transistors are the same and are the SS8050 model. The diods I now see are written on the board and they are 1n4148. And I have checked again and D4 is there

Comment: I've added an extra explanation about those transistors.

Comment: Thanks Andy. You helped me understand quite a lot of what's going on in this circuitry.

Comment: D4: definately not MOSFETS.

Comment: Ah, so C2 would explain why D2 and/or D3 is there...to clamp/block the inevitable negative swings.

Answer (score 4):

1. It's probably for fail-safe. There is no need of a flyback diode when the transistor is driven from the emitter as shown, by the way. The charge pump (C2/C3/D3/D3) means that even if the MCU output gets stuck high or low, the relay will drop out.
2. Probably a square wave as Andy says. Average voltage will be about 1/2 Vcc, minus a bit because of loading.
3. See 1.
4. It's probably to deal with a transistor failing short, but requires more analysis. There may be something wrong with your tracing wrt the relay connections, also needs values for the resistors.

These are all cheap jellybean parts, but you are clearly messing with a safety-critical part of the circuitry so be careful in any modifications. In particular do NOT remove or bypass any hardware safety cutoffs such as thermal fuses or mechanical thermostats.